# Is it bad leaving SharedPreferences & Editor open

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

e.g. you have this class

```
private SharedPreferences sp
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor

protected void onCreate(..) {
this.sp = ...
this.editor = this.sp.edit();
}
```

Is it bad to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shared preferences are ok, the editor isn't.
As long as you do not call editor's commit or apply, the values are not written to the preferences.file and I think you also will not get the values when reading from sp.

So as a habit, always do this when writing a preference value (Java)

```
sp.edit().putString(key, value).apply()
```

Or putInt, putBoolean etc.

Comment: Is apply() & commit() the same?

Comment: Apply is asynchronous where as commit is synchronous